# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'photoURL')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am creating a Chat application using React with Firebase. On the other pages of my application, I successfully got all the data that I needed especially the photoURL in the Firestore, but I got an error to the receiver after sending a message saying that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'photoURL')" in the userInfo. I checked the array using the `console.log(Object.entries(chats));` to check the array and I think it's correct. Is it on the ChatContext where the problem is or in the Array.map?

This is the error message to the receiver:

[image]

And here is the code I used:

```js
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { ChatContext } from "../context/ChatContext";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const Chats = () => {
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { dispatch } = useContext(ChatContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getChats = () => {
            const unsub = onSnapshot(
                doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid),
                (doc) => {
                    setChats(doc.data());
                }
            );

            return () => {
                unsub();
            };
        };

        currentUser.uid && getChats();
    }, [currentUser.uid]);

    const handleSelect = (u) => {
        dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_USER", payload: u });
    };

    console.log(Object.entries(chats));

    return (
        <div className='chats'>
            {Object.entries(chats)
                ?.sort((a, b) => b[1].date - a[1].date)
                .map((chat) => (
                    <div
                        className='userChat'
                        key={chat[0]}
                        onClick={() => handleSelect(chat[1].userInfo)}
                    >
                        <img src={chat[1].userInfo.photoURL} alt='' />
                        <div className='userChatInfo'>
                            <span>{chat[1].userInfo.displayName}</span>
                            <p>{chat[1].lastMessage?.text}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chats;
```

I'm really confused because the sender did not get the error but the receiver got it and I think there is a problem in the ChatContext.

Here is the code of the ChatContext.js:

```js
import {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer,
} from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

export const ChatContext = createContext();

export const ChatContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const INITIAL_STATE = {
    chatId: "null",
    user: {},
  };

  const chatReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "CHANGE_USER":
        return {
          user: action.payload,
          chatId:
            currentUser.uid > action.payload.uid
              ? currentUser.uid + action.payload.uid
              : action.payload.uid + currentUser.uid,
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(chatReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider value={{ data:state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is the result of the array when I used the `console.log(Object.entries(chats));`

[image]

And I used it in this part:

```js
console.log(Object.entries(chats));

    return (
        <div className='chats'>
            {Object.entries(chats)
                ?.sort((a, b) => b[1].date - a[1].date)
                .map((chat) => (
                    <div
                        className='userChat'
                        key={chat[0]}
                        onClick={() => handleSelect(chat[1].userInfo)}
                    >
                        <img src={chat[1].userInfo.photoURL} alt='' />
                        <div className='userChatInfo'>
                            <span>{chat[1].userInfo.displayName}</span>
                            <p>{chat[1].lastMessage?.text}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
```

And saying the error is here:

`<img src={chat[1].userInfo.photoURL} alt='' />`

I used this GitHub from Safak (Lama Dev) as my reference for my application. I got the Error at the Chat.jsx file:
https://github.com/safak/youtube2022/tree/react-chat

Comment: What's in `chat[1]` and `chat[1].userInfo` when you're attempting to access them?

Comment: I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Can you log it right before you call the variable?

Comment: Yes, I can log it right before calling it. I think the problem is in the **handleSelect** where the ChatContext is because it holding the userInfo before the photoURL and it's because the receiver got the error and the sender did not. I'm really confused right now.